# struct and pointer not working properly in c

Tags: c

I am writing a program in c which traverse a tree in in-order, pre-order and post-order . this code is not compiling properly . it  shows a error saying "unknown type name 'node'"

```
     struct node
     {
         int value;
         node* left;
         node* right;
     };


struct node* root;

struct node* insert(struct node* r, int data);
void inOrder(struct node* r);
void preOrder(struct node* r);
void postOrder(struct node* r);
```

what i am missing ?

Comment: `node* left;` --> `struct node* left;`, same for `right`

Comment: Alternatively `typedef struct node { .. struct node* left; ...} node_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change inside structure

```
struct node
     {
         int value;
         struct  node* left; //Changed
         struct  node* right;
     };
```